# Observe a property from a viewController

Tags: ios, swift

I try to observe a property in a view controller, for example, isBeingDimissed property.. But It doesnt seem to work... Only when I set the options to `.initial` do I see that it works.

But I wanna observe new values.. Am I missing anything?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var firstViewController = FirstViewController.init()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        firstViewController.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(UIViewController.isBeingPresented), options: .new, context: &myContext)
    }

    @IBAction func tapButton(_ sender: Any) {
        present(firstViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        print("let me see the change:", keyPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: @matt the property is a property of view controller... And according to documentation, if the viewcontroller is a subclass of nsobject.. its properties should be observable.. no? At least least if you pass in the option as "initial". The observeValue function is actually triggered..

Comment: @matt ok, then since in this case.. isBeingPresented is a property of UIViewController.. Is there anyway I can make it dynamic or observe the property?

Comment: @matt fantastic conclusion.. Can I ask if there is a solution or an alternative?

Comment: What do you want to do when this pseudo-property changes? Can you use the regular viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear for that?

Comment: @Yonat to observe its changes from another class indirectly or directly..

Comment: Yes, but what for? What does that other class need to do, and when? There may be better ways to invoke this behavior.